# How to find the biggest number in a string that contains not just numbers but words?

Tags: string, int, indexof, names

How to find the biggest number in a string that contains not just numbers but words?

For example:

```
String naa = "John 19, Reuben 21, sbu 6, Derick 33";
```

I need to be able to find the highest age no mater the names and ages entered.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are trying to use but one way to do this in ruby for example would be

```
str = "John 19, Reuben 21, sbu 6, Derick 33;"
str.gsub(/\d+/).map { |i| i.to_i }.max
```

What this does is the following:

```
str.gsub(/\d+/)
```

Returns all the numbers as an enumerator

The map command then changes them all to integers and returns an Array with the integers.
Then we just call max on that array.

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
    String[] ss = "John 19, Reuben 21, sbu 6, Derick 33;".split("[^\\d]");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ss));
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(String s:ss){
        try{
        if (Math.max(Integer.valueOf(s), max) != max){
            max = Integer.valueOf(s);
        }
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in java

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]?[0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(naa) ;  
List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (m.find()) {
int age = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    listInt.add(age);
}

int max = Collections.max(listInt);
System.out.println( max);
```